# ShellJS start script but don't stop the current flow

Tags: javascript, automation, automated-tests, codeceptjs

I'm using `codeceptjs` with `shelljs`.

In one of tests I'm invoking `go` application like this :

```
const shell = require('shelljs')

Given('Member starts call', () => {
    shell.exec('./myGoApplication -cc call', true)
});

Then('I wait for {}', async (element) => {
    await I.waitForElement("~" + element, 20)
})
```

So first step in test is invoked and the go application is started with shell command.

Then next one step is codeceptjs wait for element but it never happens. And in console I see only the 'go program'

When application is started its blocking my other JS to be executed (Its codeceptjs tests).

Does someone has idea how not to interrupt further JS execution?

https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs

Comment: Can you paste more code to see how it is?

Comment: @Sohan added more code

Comment: The below solution worked for you? 
If your current code you have passed `true` flag

Comment: @Sohan the only worked if I pass `{async: true}` exactly

Comment: right, problem solved :0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You should use async option. Please check the docs by "async" keyword

Comment: [Don't paste images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/13860)